# MariaDB Galera Cluster (master-master) does sync Tables but no data

Tags: mariadb, galera

I'm currently experiencing some sync-issues on my MariaDB Galera Cluster which is a master-master scenario. I've got everything set up properly and the cluster is syncing the DDL changes flawless.

The output of the DB-Parameters seems right because every relevant variable is correct (both nodes are: ready, have the same sync-state and no errors are detected).

I made the check by creating a table and checking if it's syncing to the other node - after that i did it backwards. Everything works except the syncing of the data from the first node to the second.

Is there a way to initiate tis sync-process manually? Might there be a log-file which i oversaw?

Best Regards 
k

Comment: Are your tables MyISAM/Aria or InnoDB?

Comment: I'm using Aria for every table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Galera only supports the **InnoDB ENGINE** (and XtraDB, which is essentially the same). While there is experimental support for MyISAM, by activating `wsrep_replicate_myisam`, that is not guaranteed to work, as it is not transactional.

The DDL that you executed worked because they do not use the ROW format, but STATEMENT-based replication.

While we could hack and maybe make it work, it would work poorly. **I highly recommend you to change the tables to InnoDB**: `ALTER TABLE your_table ENGINE=InnoDB, FORCE;` After that, any change will be synced automatically as desired.

References:

- MariaDB Galera Cluster limitations: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-galera-cluster-known-limitations/
- Aria is not supported: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/codership-team/-VTXuYVnbN0/d-v4NVTQDNwJ

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful answer. I converted the tables to InnoDB (a script for generating the command for each table can be found on SO) and exported the whole database. Then I dropped everything and restored the database to transfer every INSERT command to the second node. Now i have a running galera Cluster, thank you very much! k

Answer (score 0):

Because I've lost quite a lot of time finding my problem, and the only searches lead me to this question.

I'll post my issue that had same symptoms - db structure was synced, but no data was showing on the other nodes, except the one I made inserts on.

Turned out that my mysqld had log-bin enabled - set server-id, log-bin file and some other log bin options.

When I turned off the log-bin options on all nodes the data started showing everywhere.
I suspect enabling https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replication-and-binary-log-system-variables/#log_slave_updates would have solved the issue, but I don't need it anyway, so I just disabled it.
I hope that helps someone to save some time.